# HttpPostedFileBase Editor Template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and have this simple ViewModel.

```
public class ArtistVM
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImgUpload { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I require a custom editor template for `HttpPostedFileBase`, so I have gone ahead and added a `HttpPostedFileBase.cshtml` to `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` inside that I have the following:

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { type = "file" })
```

This seem to work OK as far as displaying the input of type file!

[image]

The problem occurs when it comes to posting and binding, my `ImgUpload` property always comes back as null, which tells me something is not right in my Editor Template.

Code for the new artist view is shown below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Artist", FormMethod.Post, new { encrypt = "multipart/form-data"})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImgUpload, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImgUpload, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImgUpload, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Artist" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And the Controller Action handling the post is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(ArtistNewVM vm)
{
    var validImageTypes = new string[]
    {
        "image/gif",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/png"
    };

    if (vm.ImgUpload == null || vm.ImgUpload.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        // ** gets inside here **
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "This field is required");
    }
    else if (!validImageTypes.Any(vm.ImgUpload.ContentType.Contains))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Please choose either a GIF, JPG or PNG image.");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do the magic
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Added Controller Action code as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have html attribute wrong in form it is `enctype` which stands for **"encoding type"** not `encrypt` [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.enctype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> > The `enctype` attribute’s purpose is to indicate how form data should be encoded prior to it being sent to the location defined in the action attribute.

Change:

```
new { encrypt = "multipart/form-data"}
```

to:

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}
```